# Find $x$ such that $\arctan(3/2)+\dots=\arctan x$

Tags: functions, problem-solving

**Find $x$ such that**

$$\arctan(3/2) + \arctan(5/4) + \arctan(-5/2) + \arctan(-8/3) = \arctan x.$$

Comment: You should leave the question here even if it has been solved. That way it may help other people with the same or similar questions in the future!

Comment: To add on Deven Ware's comment, if one of the answers helped you to reach a solution you should accept it by click on the check mark under the vote up/down arrows; and if none of the answers helped, you should post your own answer and accept it (although you have to wait for two days before accepting your own answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use the fact if $x > 0$, the argument of the complex number $x+iy$ is $\tan^{-1} \left(\frac{x}{y}\right)$. So if you compute the product

$$(2+3i)(4+5i)(2-5i)(3-8i) = 920 - 531i$$

you get that

$$\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right) + \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{5}{4}\right) + \tan^{-1}\left(-\frac{5}{2}\right) + \tan^{-1}\left(-\frac{8}{3}\right) \equiv \tan^{-1}\left(-\frac{531}{920}\right) \mod 2\pi$$

By computing both side on a calculator, you can check this actually an equality.

Comment: Yes, it is possible that the left hand side of the expression is not in the range of arctan. Good catch...

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** A repetition of applying the formula

$$ \tan(\alpha \pm \beta) = \frac{\tan \alpha \pm \tan \beta}{1 \mp \tan \alpha \tan \beta} $$

gives you the answer.

Comment: While that does result in the answer, why is that procedure motivated? As in, what does the student gain from this exercise other than the repetition of a formula?

Comment: @Limitless Amongst other things, the student learns how to do certain types of logical operations, and learns that this sort of expression is necessarily rational. There is a lot to be learned from working out these sorts of problems by hand.

Comment: @Limitless: If one does not work out mathematics problems in details, he will not learn mathematics.

Answer (score 2):

Take $\tan$ of both sides, and repeatedly apply the compound angle formula.

Comment: I don't see how there's motivation in the closed form. This strikes me as the type of problem best left to Wolfram Alpha, just as one leaves the integration of  $\frac{x^5+x}{x^3+x^2+1}$ to Wolfram Alpha. Do you see how or why this equation would be a motivated exercise?

Comment: I can't think of a reason, other than learning the formula for $\tan(A+B)$

Comment: @DanielLittlewood I think it is generally useful to learn not just such formulas, but how to apply them.

Comment: I agree, but I didn't set the exercise :-)

Answer (score 2):

Let $\omega_1= 2+3i, \omega_2=4+5i, \omega_3=2-5i , \omega_4=3-8i$. Then

$$\arg(\omega_1)= \arctan(\frac{3}{2}), ...$$

Finc $\omega_1 \omega_2 \omega_3 \omega_4 =a+bi$ and then

$$\frac{b}{a}= \arg(\omega_1 \omega_2 \omega_3 \omega_4 ) =\arctan(x) \,.$$

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
& {} \quad \tan(a+b+c+d) \\
& = \frac{\tan a+\tan b+\tan c+\tan d\  \overbrace{ - \tan a\tan b\tan c - \cdots}^\text{4 terms}}{1-\  \underbrace{\tan a \tan b- \cdots}_\text{6 terms} +\tan a\tan b\tan c\tan d}
\end{align}

Therefore
\begin{align}
& {} \quad \tan\Big(\arctan(3/2) + \arctan(5/4) + \arctan(-5/2) + \arctan(-8/3)\Big) \\
& = \frac{\frac32 + \frac54 + \frac{-5}2 +\frac{-8}3 - (\text{sum of four terms, each a product of three numbers})}{1 - (\text{sum of six terms, each a product of two numbers}) + (\text{a product of four numbers}))}
\end{align}

You get a number.  Then you say $\tan x=\text{that number}$, and find the tangent.